# Removing zeros from a column with pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-conversion

I am using pandas and matplotlib to evaluate an excel sheet that I have converted to a dataframe. However, two of my columns have zeros as values in some of the rows, which I need to remove. We are talking a couple thousand rows for the dataframe total.

The zeros only appear in two of my 8 columns. I'd like to remove any rows that have zeros in one or both of those two columns.

Does anyone know how I may go about doing this? I've tried 
df.loc[(df!=0).any(1)] but to no avail.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean filling the zero-valued entries with some other value, or dropping the two zero-containing columns entirely?

Comment: Elaborate your question a little more

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, to drop all columns where the column as all zeros, you can use:

```
df.drop(df.columns[df.eq(0).all()], axis=1)
```

---

Update:  Where columns A and C are your two checking columns, you can use this:

```
df.drop(df.index[(df.C.eq(0) | df.A.eq(0))])
```

Comment: My apologies, I should have stated my question better. I want to remove the rows with zeros not the columns or perhaps replace the zeros with the mean of that particular column.

Comment: The zeros only appear in two of my 8 columns. I'd like to remove any rows that have zeros in one or both of those two columns.